# UITextField adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth not working if text is a single word

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

[image: example] [image: example2]

I have a UITextField that is in a specific view with constraints. It works flawlessly if the text is not a single word. But as you can see it in the above image, if the text is only one word, it does not adjust the font size to fit. How can I fix it? Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

    lazy var textInput : UITextField = {
        let textInput = UITextField()
        textInput.textAlignment = .center
        textInput.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textInput.minimumFontSize = 10;
        textInput.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
        textInput.backgroundColor = .yellow
        myView.addSubview(textInput)
        var lConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textInput, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        var toConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textInput, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        var trConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textInput, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        var bConst = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textInput, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([lConst,toConst,trConst,bConst])

        return textInput
    } ()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        _ = textInput
        textInput.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 200)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "character" instead of "word" (looking to your images), I think your problem is, that by default the first character is uppercase. If you want to start your text with lowercase character you have to set this:

```
textInput.autocapitalizationType = .none
```

Edit: Sorry I just misinterpreted your images and don't saw, that your letter is cut at top and bottom.

I wrote your code with a little bit different layout syntax and it works fine, even when the view is smaller than your font size.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var myView:UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

lazy var textInput : UITextField = {
    let textInput = UITextField()
    textInput.textAlignment = .center
    textInput.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textInput.minimumFontSize = 10;
    textInput.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    textInput.backgroundColor = .yellow
    return textInput
} ()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupLayout()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func setupLayout(){
    view.addSubview(myView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180),
        myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180)
    ])
    textInput.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 200)
    myView.addSubview(textInput)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        textInput.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:myView.topAnchor),
        textInput.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.trailingAnchor),
        textInput.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.bottomAnchor),
        textInput.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.leadingAnchor)
    ])
}
}
```

Comment: Why? I also want to use uppercase characters.

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted your images. Updated answer